# Javascript if value includes number range

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a value includes certain number range.

I found a way but it seems like the hard way, i'm pretty sure that there is an easier way to do this.

This is what i tried

```
if($(attrPTVal).val().includes('SCR1')){
  if (($(attrPSVal).val().includes('From 2 cm2') ) || ($(attrPSVal).val().includes('From 2.1 cm2') ) || ($(attrPSVal).val().includes('From 2.2 cm2') ) ){
    var setup_price = '2.14';
  }
  if (($(attrPSVal).val().includes('From 3 cm2') ) || ($(attrPSVal).val().includes('From 3.1 cm2') ) || ($(attrPSVal).val().includes('From 3.2 cm2') ) ){
    var setup_price = '5.14';
  }
}
```

Comment: Will `$(attrPSVal).val()` be equal to `'From 2 cm2'` or is that just the part of that string? Can the number be something other than what is mentioned here like `2.5`?

Comment: The part of the string will includes for sure the words 'from' and 'cm2'. For example if the number will be between 2 and 3 it will return 2.14 and if it is between 3 to 4 it will return 5.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, if the middle digit of the value is 2, 2.1 or 2.2, then return 2.14.

Otherwise, if the value is 3, 3.1 or 3.2, then return 5.14.

You could get the middle value with regex and then check the range:

```js
    var inputValue = "SCR1 - From 2 cm2" // $(attrPTVal).val();
    if(inputValue.includes('SCR1')){
      var value = inputValue.replace(/.*From (\d\.*\d*) cm2.*/, "$1");
      var setup_price = 0;
      if (value >=2 && value <= 2.2) {
          setup_price = '2.14';
      } else if (value >=3 && value <= 3.2) {
          setup_price = '5.14';
      }
      console.log(setup_price);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this way but it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: I tried this `if($(attrPTVal).val().includes('SCR1')){
                                var value = $(attrPSVal).val().replace(/.*From (\d\.*\d*) cm2.*/, "$1");
                                if (value >=2 && value <= 2.2) {
                                    var print_price = '2.14';
                                } else if (value >=3 && value <= 3.2) {
                                    var print_price = '5.14';
                                }
                            }`

Comment: What is the value of `$(attrPTVal).val()`?

Comment: I want to return these values only if `$(attrPTVal).val()` includes `'SCR1'`. I don't think that the problem is there. The way i wrote in my question works but i'm looking another way from statement OR `||`.

Comment: Yes I understand. I was wondering what the value is as it may change the regex pattern. See the above snippet.

Comment: Ok, i can understand your question now. There are two values. The `$(attrPTVal).val()` which will return value if it includes 'SCR1' and the `$(attrPSVal).val()` which will return values if it includes the word 'From' and 'cm2' and numbers between '2 to 2.2' and diferrent values if it includes '3 to 3.2'.

Comment: It worked. I did some changes, nothing serious, and works perfectly. Thank you!!!